# How to express the process of making communication more elegant?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, vocabulary, phrases

I'm looking for a phrase that would express the act of reducing some convoluted idea into one that can be well understood to a layman or perhaps crafting a piece of media to make it express the message in a more elegant way. I suppose I could say:

> We need to ***round off / polish up*** the presentation

if the presentation only needed some finishing touches but I'm interested in a phrase that would describe the whole process of gradually improving some communication.

I think the closest phrase for what I'm looking for is ***to smooth out***, could I use in the indicated context?

Answer (score 1):

We could **simplify** a convoluted document to ease understanding.

We could **improve** a document in various stages of its production, and **refine** or **tweak** it at the final stage.

As a side note, I usually avoid using phrasal verbs, which are usually longer, if there are alternatives.

"[T]he meaning of a verb often changes significantly when it is used in a phrasal verb."  This could make phrasal verbs harder to understand.

Phrasal verbs are also "less appropriate in formal language.  If you are writing a formal document or an academic essay, try to avoid using phrasal verbs and use more formal alternatives instead."

[Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/What-are-phrasal-verbs-and-how-do-you-use-them#:%7E:text=A%20phrasal%20verb%20is%20a,%2C%20an%20adverb%2C%20or%20both.)

Comment: Thanks - so could you also use the slightly informal "smooth out" to name the process of making the presentation flow more naturally?